# how to increase the left div size within the right div in css

Tags: html, css

I want to increase the left size along with the right div. But left div didn't behave as i want to be. What is the solution.

I keep the code right here bellow:

```
    <div id="bn-container">
        <div id="bn-leftside">
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="left" style="xhtml" />
        </div>
        <div id="bn-rightside">
            <div id="bn-component" style="float:left;">
                <?php if($this->countModules('breadcrumb')) { ?>
                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="breadcrumb" style="xhtml" />
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <div id="moduletable_space"></div>
                <?php } ?>
                <jdoc:include type="component" />
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="inset" />
            </div>
            <div id="bn-rightmodule" style="float:right;">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="right" style="xhtml" />
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#bn-leftside{
    width:225px;
    background:#3e5955;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
height:auto;
}

#bn-rightside{
    width:780px;
    background:#FFF;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    height:auto;
}
```

Comment: Some of the code is missing. Edit and update accordingly please.

Comment: Also, when giving a problem, it's best if you A) say exactly what you want to happen, and B) say exactly what is happening

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is a dynamic joomla code. you should provide html from rendered page's view source.

I'm giving my opinion if I'm judging your question right

Both column are separate height of both `div` depends on content `inside` div if we do not give fixed height.

Here are some method to achieve equal height code : http://buildinternet.com/2009/07/four-methods-to-create-equal-height-columns/ choose what suit you.